# How to use vectorization to improve python performance?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I am doing backtest on my trading strategy which is a daily strategy and there will have 2 dataframes.
The first dataframe is the daily trading signal which has 2 columns: trading date and trading signal (1:buy, -1:sell, 0:no trade). Example:

```
         Date  trading_signal
0  2023-01-01               1
1  2023-01-02              -1
2  2023-01-03               1
3  2023-01-04               1
```

The second dataframe is the minute data of each trading date and there are 6 columns: Date, time (each minute), open price, high price, low price, close price. Example:

```
          Date  Time  open  high  low  close
0   2023-01-01     1    50    60   49     55             
1   2023-01-01     2    55    56   53     54             
2   2023-01-01     3    54    60   54     59              
3   2023-01-01     4    59    62   50     51               
4   2023-01-01     5    51    55   49     51               
5   2023-01-01     6    51    62   50     58               
6   2023-01-01     7    58    58   56     56               
7   2023-01-01     8    56    58   53     54               
8   2023-01-01     9    54    60   53     59               
9   2023-01-01    10    59    63   58     60              
10  2023-01-02     1    60    62   55     56              
......
......
```

This is a daily strategy so that trade-date-1 and trade-date-2 is independent (1 can be long and 1 can be short).

What I want to do is

1. base on trade signal, use the open price to enter the trade
2. then before trading date end, if hit stop-loss (eg, 20), place a reversal trade (original signal is 1 then reversal is -1, vice versa) in the next minute (eg, Time 3 hit stop-loss, then Time 4 do reversal)
3. if before trading date end, hit profit-taker, the profit of that trading date is the profit taker
4. if no stop-loss and profit-taker, then profit-or-loss is last minute close - first minute open

Below is the code snippet

```
for i in range(len(df_signal)):
    df_min_data = np.where(df_min_raw['Date'] = df_signal.iloc[i,'Date'])
    for j in range(len(df_min_data)):
        #second loop to calculate the profit-and-loss
        ....
        ....
    #end of 2nd loop
#end of 1st loop
```

I have written the python code to loop through the 2 dataframes to achieve the above. However, the performance is quite bad given the large amount of data.
I am expecting an output to tell me the trading activities (based on the input signal and whether there is reversal). Below is the sample dataframe. This dataframe can be a new dataframe or the 4 columns can be appended to the signal dataframe. Thanks.

```
         Date  trade_1st  pnl_1st  trade_2nd  pnl_2nd
0  2023-01-01          1       10          0        0
1  2023-01-02         -1      -20          1        5
2  2023-01-03          1       30          0        0
3  2023-01-04         -1      -20          1       -3
```

Any idea how to use vectorization to improve the performance?

Comment: When you say "hit stop-loss", do you mean "when the 'low' price is <= the stop loss value"?  When you say "profit-taker", do you mean "when the 'high' price is >= the profit taker value"?  Are those constants?  When do you actually do buys and sells?

Comment: The entry price will always be the open of the first min bar of that trade date. eg, For trade-date 2023-01-02, the strategy is a short (-1) and the entry price will be the open of Time: 1.

Comment: stop-loss (eg: 20unit)
For long(1), entry price (open of first min bar) - 20 < low
For short(-1), entry price (open of first min bar) +20 > high

profit-taker (eg: 30unit)
For long(1), entry price (open of first min bar) + 30 >high
For short(-1), entry price (open of first min bar) -30 > low

thank you!

Comment: OK, so tell me what the OUTPUT of that dataframe would be.  The entire high-to-low spread is only 14, so nothing changes.  What would your result be?

Comment: I am expecting an output to tell me the trading activities (based on the input signal and whether there is reversal). Below is the sample dataframe. This dataframe can be a new dataframe or the 4 columns can be appended to the signal dataframe. Thanks.

         Date  trade_1st  pnl_1st  trade_2nd  pnl_2nd
0  2023-01-01          1       10          0        0
1  2023-01-02         -1      -20          1        5
2  2023-01-03          1       30          0        0
3  2023-01-04         -1      -20          1       -3

Comment: Please add that to your question so we can see it formatted properly.

Comment: I doubt there is any way to vectorize this.  Too much conditional processing  It is going to be line-by-line process.  There's no need to extract a sub-df for each day -- you can just enumerate the rows (with `iterrows`, maybe) and watch for the date to change.  That will help the speed.